# UISearchBar in UINavigationController with cancel button not selectable

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, focus, uisearchbar

I have added a UISearchBar to the UINavigationController just fine, but as soon as I add the cancel button to the search bar I can no longer select it by touching it.

The code I'm using to create the search bar and add it is:

```
UISearchBar *theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f,0.0f)];
theSearchBar.delegate = self;
[theSearchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search iPad"];
[theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
self.navigationItem.titleView = theSearchBar;
self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[theSearchBar release];
```

If I remove the line to add the cancel button I'm able to focus on the search bar and the search works correctly. As soon as I put that line in, it displays properly, but I can no longer focus on it.

I've tried putting it into a simple UIView container, but that didn't solve the problem either.

What about adding the cancel button could be causing this to fail?

UPDATE:
I ended up not using the cancel button because I determined it wasn't necessary the way the search bar was being used.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend a UISearchDisplayController: [apple docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
  It has a cancel button built right in, and by placing it in interface builder you can save a lot of code.  Less code = less bugs.